# Annual Count by Criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis

I am working on a project with our HR department. 
I have a table called [EEMaster] that keeps a record of the Active/Termed employees. 
It is updated from a flat File using a Slowly Changing Dimension.

At the end of the year I need a count of the number of Active employees and the number of termed employees and then the year.

Here is an example of the data I need returned annually.

```
             | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 |
HistoricalHC | 447  | 419  | 420  | 418  |
NumbTermEmp  | 57   | 67   |  51  | 42   |
```

I currently have the data connected to an excel spreadsheet providing a rolling count by Division. I use the following columns from the [EEMaster] for it.

- ChangeStatus (1/0 from the SCD)
- EmpStatusName ("Active" for current employees and "Withdrawn" for Termed Employees)
- HireYear (set to All in the pivot table)
- Term Year (set to 2013 in the pivot table)
- PONumb (The employee numbers, I use for the count)

I have created a table to input the data into, I will manually load the previous years (counts)into the table since the current development is a rolling number. What I want to do is to develop an SSIS package that will capture the count on Jan 1 of 2014 and insert the # of "Active Employees", "Termed Employees" and the Year that just finished into a table.

UPDATE:

I have created two queries. One that provides the number of Active Employees

```
SELECT COUNT([PersNo]) AS HistoricalHC
FROM [dbo].[EEMaster]
WHERE [ChangeStatus] = 'Current' AND [EmpStatusName] = 'Active'
```

it returns

```
|HistoricHC|
|418       |
```

And another that provides the number of terms by Term Year

```
SELECT COUNT([PersNo]) AS NumbOfTermEE
FROM [dbo].[EEMaster]
WHERE [ChangeStatus] = 'Current' AND [EmpStatusName] = 'Withdrawn' 
AND [TermYear] = '2013'
```

it returns

```
|NumbOfTermEE|
|42          |
```

I need the [TermYear] to be dynamic. Since this will run on Jan 1st of every year. It would need to pull the number of terms for the previous year (continually).

Then I need both of these numbers to be added into the new row with the year the data was calculated.

```
|Year|HistoricalHC|NumbOfTermEmp|
|2010|447         |57           |
|2011|419         |67           |
|2012|420         |51           |
|2013|418         |42           |
```

Comment: Thank you Bill for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a syntax of a case expression that does an aggregate to add a few for different things.

```
Sum(Case when (expression) then 1 end)
```

You also want to group by year it seems in the columns so you can easily pivot on that.  You mention dynamic but I don't really know if you need to get much dynamic for just the year logic.  I am not really getting if you want a SQL statement to go in a data flow to generate an output of an Excel sheet or not.  Basically if you want just a grid with one row being one set of conditions and another being another.  I would do a 'union' of two or more selects as long as it is not too large it should not be that hard.  Here is a simple self extracting example with dummy data to see what I mean more.

It will run as is in SQL Management Studio 2005 and up.

```
declare @Person Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

insert into @Person values ('Brett'),('Sean'),('Chad'),('Michael'),('Ray'),('Erik'),('Queyn');

declare @Orders table ( OrderID int identity, PersonID int, OrderCnt int, dt Date);

insert into @Orders values (1, 10, '1-7-11'),(1, 12, '2-12-12'),(2, 20, '7-1-13'),(2, 12, '1-5-10'),(3, 20, '6-4-11')
,(3, 12, '2-3-10'),(3, 6, '6-10-10'),(4, 20, '7-10-11'),(5, 20, '1-8-10'),(5, 9, '2-10-11'),
(6, 20, '3-1-11'),(6, 34, '4-6-12'),(7, 20, '5-1-11'),(7, 12, '6-8-12'),(7, 56, '7-25-13')

-- As is just joining sets
select *
from @Person p
    join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID
order by dt

-- Years on the rows
select
    year(o.dt) as Year
,   sum(o.OrderCnt) as Orders
,   count(p.personID) as People
,   count(distinct p.personID) as DistinctPeople
from @Person p
    join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID
group by year(o.dt)

-- Custom grouping on rows and doing the years with pivots for the columns
Select 
    'BulkOrders' as Description
,   sum(case when year(o.dt) = '2010' then OrderCnt end) as [2010Orders]
,   sum(case when year(o.dt) = '2011' then OrderCnt end) as [2011Orders]
,   sum(case when year(o.dt) = '2012' then OrderCnt end) as [2012Orders]
,   sum(case when year(o.dt) = '2013' then OrderCnt end) as [2013Orders]
,   sum(OrderCnt) as Totals
from @Person p
    join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID
union
select
    'OrdersByPerson'
,   Count(case when year(o.dt) = '2010' then p.personID  end) 
,   Count(case when year(o.dt) = '2011' then p.personID end) 
,   Count(case when year(o.dt) = '2012' then p.personID end) 
,   Count(case when year(o.dt) = '2013' then p.personID end) 
,   Count(p.personID)
from @Person p
    join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID
union
select
    'OrdersByPersonDistinct'
,   Count(distinct case when year(o.dt) = '2010' then p.personID  end)
,   Count(distinct case when year(o.dt) = '2011' then p.personID end) 
,   Count(distinct case when year(o.dt) = '2012' then p.personID end) 
,   Count(distinct case when year(o.dt) = '2013' then p.personID end) 
,   Count(distinct p.personID)
from @Person p
    join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. To give you a little more insight into what the customer wants. We have HR data that comes from our SAP system in the form of an Excel file. I have created an SSIS package that will capture that data from the file monthly and update a table using a SCD2. I then use Excel (per the customers request) to bring the data into a series of pivot tables. Essentially breaking the one large table down into several smaller reports with charts and calculations. The final component to this is that they want an overall count of employees vs an overall count of terms for the yrs end

Comment: BTW, Awesome example. I may actually have use of this on another project. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, SSIS is definitely the right mechanism for what you want to do it seems then.  SSIS is great for taking a flat file to a database, manipulating it and then delivering it back out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I cam up with.

I will create an SSIS package that will run the following Stored Procedure.

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TORateFY] (Year,HistoricalHC,NumbTermedEmp)
    SELECT  DISTINCT YEAR(GETDATE()) AS [Year],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EmpStatusName = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HistoricalHC,
        SUM(CASE WHEN EmpStatusName = 'Withdrawn' AND TermYear = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumbOfTermEE
    FROM    dbo.EEMaster
```

This will be scheduled to run Annually on the 31st of Dec.

Answer (score 0):

Update to my previous Answer:

I worked with a guy on another forum and he provided an excellent script that will give the correct count for both the active and termed employees on a monthly basis instead of waiting until the end of the year to get an overall count. This puts the reporting more inline with what was originally done manually.

```
MERGE dbo.TORateFY AS tgt
USING (
   SELECT DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS [Year],
     SUM(CASE WHEN EmpStatusName = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HistoricalHC,
     SUM(CASE WHEN EmpStatusName = 'Withdrawn' AND TermYear = DATENAME(YEAR,
     GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumbOfTermEE
   FROM dbo.EEMaster
   WHERE ChangeStatus = 'Current'
    AND EmpStatusName IN ('Active', 'Withdrawn')
    OR TermYear <= DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE())
  ) AS src ON src.[Year] = tgt.[Year]
WHEN MATCHED
  THEN UPDATE
    SET tgt.HistoricalHC = src.HistoricalHC,
        tgt.NumbTermedEmp = src.NumbOfTermEE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (
             [Year],
             HistoricalHC,
             NumbTermedEmp
             )
VALUES (
         src.[Year],
         src.HistoricalHC,
         src.NumbOfTermEE
             );
```

I wanted to share the in case anyone else ran into a similar situation.

Thank you everyone for your input and guidance.